# Receiving memory warnings when loading gif animation from bundle

Tags: ios

[Here the screen shot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FruW2.png)

Here I am loading gif files after that in output, I am getting warning like connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died followed by memory warnings after that my app is crashing.

Comment: You are simply running out of memory because loading all the uncompressed video data into memory is allocating too much memory, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/36343926/763355

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at the NSLog warnings it seems your app is having issues loading the GIF images. Apple does recommend using PNG images over other formats for iOS. I've created a custom button class in my designs and animated from one PNG image to another and this approach seems to work fine.
How big are the GIFs remember you are loading it 11 times and when an iOS app gets to approx 70 - 100Mb (depending on device and other factors) you will start to see memory warnings and app maybe terminated.
An excellent tool for monitoring your memory usage is the instruments allocations tool. It shows how much memory your app is using in real time and when a memory warning is triggered. 
Also you could create the UIImage outside the for loop and reference the single UIImage for each button rather than loading the resource for every button