# UIImageView Animation too much memory consumption

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, memory, uiimageview

I have a problem with memory and images that I am animating. First thing first, I am using ARC. On my initial screen I have about 60 images to animate. I am using this code for animation:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int animationImageCount = 61;
for (int i = 1; i < animationImageCount; i++) {
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s-%d", i]]];
}
self.fullAnimatedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"s-%d", animationImageCount - 1]];

self.animatedImageView.image = self.fullAnimatedImage;
self.animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithArray:images];
self.animatedImageView.animationDuration = images.count/30;
self.animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.animatedImageView startAnimating];

// since there is no official callback method when UIImageView animation completes,
// we can just call a method after animation time has passed
[self performSelector:@selector(animationFinished) withObject:nil
           afterDelay:self.animatedImageView.animationDuration];
```

The problem is that memory consumption is about 300 MB and of course it crashes on iPhone 4. When I comment out that part of code, memory consumption is about 40 MB, that's ok. I've tried setting image property to nil and nothing. I've tried to put it in `@autoreleasepool {}` but it does not release it's content. Do you have any idea how to optimise this?

Comment: what is the fullAnimatedImage for ? As you already given the array of images to animate, y do u set the image for the imageview again ?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I don't need that. The problem is that a cannot use fromPath method from UIImage because I am using xcassets, and that method is not caching images.

Comment: What's the animation duration? Half a second for each image? Would it be easier/better to use a timer to toggle between the images? That way you don't need to hold the actual images in memory. You can just load them one at a time. Alternatively, could you wrap this animation up as a video or something and use that instead?

Comment: Aniamtion duration is number of pictures / 30, the problem is caching

Comment: Hello @Flipper did you find any solution, I am having same problem on swift 3. Please share if any workaround is available.

Answer (score 3):

You should try replacing `[UIImage imageNamed:]` with `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:]`.

From the docs:

> If you have an image file that will only be displayed once and wish to ensure that it does not get added to the system’s cache, you should instead create your image using imageWithContentsOfFile:. This will keep your single-use image out of the system image cache, potentially improving the memory use characteristics of your app.

Comment: I have images in xcassets, I can't use that function

Comment: In that case I would move these specific images out of the Asset Catalog and into your project directly — then you'll be able to use `imageWithContentsOfFile:`.

Answer (score 0):

How big is each image that you are loading (pixel wise and file size wise)?

Your best bet is to optimise the images to reduce their file sizes/memory requirements. Try using jpg instead of png if you haven't yet. If they are part of a video sequence you can safely reduce their quality further without having a knockoff on perceived quality.

Comment: Each image is 3,5 kb. I will try

Comment: Images are uncompressed in memory, you are looking at the compressed size which is completely misleading.

Answer (score 0):

So after a period of time, I decided to go different way. From 60 images, I have created 10 images. I do not have every image for every object, but one images for all objects. For example, if you have 3 cars, and image for each car, and another n images for moving every three point to the left, that's now one image for all three cars. For same objects, I have created one whole image. After that, I have created image view for each image. I needed to know for every image what was image object final position. For example, car is going from right to left. So I have placed that one image with all my cars on the right, out of view bounds. And that is the logic for every other image. After that I just animate UIImageViews position. I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is with the basic approach. You simply cannot hold all the decoded images in memory at the same time. I wrote a specific blog post on this subject which you can read [here](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post5_video_and_memory_usage_on_ios_devices). The solution is to use a different approach, so that you only hold 1 frame of decoded image data in memory at once. That means frames of data need to be dynamically loaded as needed.